# Is it ok to quote short solutions from GitHub issues *verbatim* as answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, external-links, attribution, blockquote

I found an answer to a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69750498/9835872) from a GitHub issue. The [solution posted in the issue](https://github.com/daniyalzade/django_reverse_admin/issues/154#issuecomment-729739280) is short and to the point.

**Is it ok that I quoted the GitHub comment *verbatim* and posted it [as my answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69750595/9835872)?** I of course attributed the original commenter.

**Edit:** Thanks for the answers, [I completely reworded](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69750595/revisions) my answer into my own words.

Comment: Generally you should be using your own words. Citing is fine, but you're just copying the entirety of someone else's answer and adding nothing to it (such as an explanation of what it does), it's not your own words at all. If you are completely reproducing someone else's answer, I would suggest you post it as a Community Wiki Answer.

Comment: The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) suggests to use quotes to *support* an answer. You could e.g. adjust the code to match the OP's example. But this might just make the answer worse if the OP chose a bad example.

Comment: IMO, it's fine in some cases. I find that sometimes not possible to meaningfully contribute more than what the quoted part already communicates. If the quoted thing already includes all the relevant information, then restating it *and* quoting seems redundant.

Comment: What is the license of content published on GitHub? For you to be able to reproduce content from there you must make sure that their license is compatible with our license.

Comment: Can you clarify what, exactly, you mean by "OK"? For example, it seems pretty clear that what you did does not violate the SO Terms of Service, but OTOH, it is possible what you did is illegal. Would that count as "OK"?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/site-policy/github-terms-of-service#5-license-grant-to-other-users may be helpful especially the "reproduce Your Content solely on GitHub" part.

Comment: If I understand it right, then the issues are under the same license than the whole repository and this specific repository is under the 3-clause BSD license (https://github.com/daniyalzade/django_reverse_admin/blob/master/LICENSE) which would make the content of the issues also under this license. Now can 3-clause BSD licensed content also be published under CC-BY-SA 4.0?

Comment: See also https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/licensing-considerations/compatible-licenses/ where it says that only material under CC-BY-SA 4.0, the Free Art license or the GPLv3 can be included in CC-BY-SA-4.0 material (if I understand it correctly). So, unless you want to opt for fair use, maybe better paraphrase the content and just link to the issue. That's my advice.

Comment: You have quoted the **entire article**, not just a small excerpt. Maybe you should contact the author of the quoted work to ask for their permission to reproduce it.

Comment: Calling it an "entire article" is pretty disingenuous, @Andrew. It's not an article at all! It's a comment on an issue on GitHub. The whole thing is maybe 2–3 sentences. Quoting any smaller portion of it would be incoherent. Putting the onus on contributors of this site to contact others for permission to reproduce everything they want to cite would be unduly burdensome and result in an enormous chilling effect on contributions, not to mention simply isn't how US copyright law assigns burdens. I'd much rather have my words quoted in full, with credit given to me, than selective paraphrasing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The attribution requirements mentioned [in another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412624/1536976) do not apply here, they are only valid for using content from Stack Overflow somewhere else and not the other way around.

With "is it ok" I take it that you mean to ask if you are allowed to do that by law, i.e. if it is legal to do so.

What you want to do is reproducing content on Stack Overflow that you haven't created yourself and that currently resides on GitHub. That means you cannot readily license it to Stack Overflow the typical way (which assumes you are the sole content creator).

Posting on Stack Overflow implies that you are allowed to use the material that you use to be published under the current content license here (i.e. CC-BY-SA-4.0).

Since the content is published on GitHub, it's worth looking at their [terms of service](https://docs.github.com/en/github/site-policy/github-terms-of-service#5-license-grant-to-other-users). Content published on GitHub can be freely re-published on GitHub but nowhere else without permission of the author unless the repository grants additional rights.

Indeed the repository in question grants additional rights, i.e. the content of this repository including the issues is under the [3-clause BSD license](https://github.com/daniyalzade/django_reverse_admin/blob/master/LICENSE).

However, that doesn't necessarily help you, because the 3-clause BSD license may not be [compatible with CC-BY-SA-4.0](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/licensing-considerations/compatible-licenses/) (only the FreeArt license, the GPLv3 license and other CC-BY-SA licenses are officially compatible).

That means that you may have breached the copyright with your post on Stack Overflow (your attribution might not change that) and the original content owner Matthias Schoettle could potentially file a DMCA take down request towards Stack Overflow and the company might have to remove that post.

To prevent that you could have asked Matthias Schoettle for permission to post his content under the content license here, but so far you haven't done that and he wouldn't necessarily have to agree to any such proposal.

Of course you could argue that the copy of this small piece of text falls under [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) but there are boundaries to fair use and they may vary from country to country.

In any case, Stack Overflow requires you additionally to [properly attribute all material that you contribute](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing), so linking to the GitHub issue is a must.

Finally let me say that paraphrasing that little piece of text isn't really difficult.

For example just change

> In the source code I discovered that it is possible to specify an admin_class for the reverse inline: .. And then in the BarInline: ..This hides the "Delete" checkbox.

to

> It is possible to specify an admin_class that does the reverse inline .. and also in BarInline .. hiding the "Delete" checkbox (see also [link to GitHub issue])

I hope it became clear where the legal pitfalls might be. I'm not a lawyer, so take it with a grain of salt. You could say that your case is "fair use" but paraphrasing such small snippets might be the safer option while being not much more work really.

Comment: Thanks! I reworded my answer.

Comment: @ruohola I think this is the more safe option. One last nitpicking. In principle your potential breach of copyright is still in the post history, i.e. still published on Stack Overflow (the post history is part of the public interface). In principle one would need to ask either a mod or staff to scrub that piece from the post history too (or do a rollback if that's possible). This is just for the sake of completeness, the risk seems to be rather hypothetical.

Comment: This answer is incorrect (in terms of the legality). Any content that ostensibly belongs on Stack Overflow (or any Stack Exchange site) would categorically fall under 17 U.S. Code § 107, or the "fair use" exception for copyrighted material, including written/published material. Content quoted or borrowed for the purposes of—among other reasons— **teaching** is considered a *fair use* and thus not prohibited by law. Ergo, content from GitHub can be used to teach someone (e.g. by answering their question on Stack Overflow) without fear of violating GitHub's license.

Comment: Legality aside, to publish *anything* on Stack Overflow requires that you comply with Stack Overflow's rules. For quoted material that means proper attribution must be given for something that isn't original to the site. In this case it is encouraged to use block quote formatting to indicate content is taken from another work, so @ruohola was fine in answering the way they did initially. However, I agree it is always *better* to paraphrase/explain in your own words when quoting something, if possible.

Comment: @TylerH You cite the U.S. code but I don't live in the US. Is it really relevant for me then? I'm not a lawyer and you can surely post that as another answer. If it wouldn't get expensive at some point, I would even like to test it and learn something. Regarding the attribution that must be given for something that isn't original to the site, i.e. incoming content, could you maybe point me to the relevant sections of the [TOS](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/free), so I know them in the future? Proper citation is surely good practice but may not always be required legally.

Comment: @Trilarion GitHub and Stack Overflow are headquartered in, and their websites hosted in, the United States, so yes, United States law applies to you. However, regarding "testing" it, there's no way to do that without someone filing a lawsuit, because that's the *only* way that copyright and fair use are "tested" (much like any laws). And in the United States, at least, judges do not look favorably upon frivolous lawsuits (such as those just designed to test some aspect of the law).

Comment: This is why the entire question is largely academic: it doesn't really *matter* what the license is for content that gets re-posted to Stack Overflow, until someone is willing to go to court over it (if you read the entire DMCA notice thread you linked under Cody's answer, you'll notice the staff ultimately just ignored it after determining it was a bogus claim. And... they weren't sued by that company for compliance to test it out, either).

Comment: @TylerH "or borrowed for the purposes of—among other reasons— teaching" I'm not even sure about that. The purpose of Stack Overflow is surely not only teaching but also to make profit. There are commercial interests involved.

Comment: Regarding attribution, that's covered in the TOS by the sentence "*You should be aware that all Public Content you contribute is available for public copy and redistribution, and **all such Public Content must have appropriate attribution**.*" (emphasis mine)

Comment: @Trilarion The purpose of a company is to provide a particular good or service. That for-profit enterprises make profits is not what is meant by "purpose". To that end, the "purpose" of Stack Overflow is to provide a repository for programming problems and their solutions. Regardless, the purpose of a specific post known as an "answer" on Stack Overflow is to provide a solution to a specific question, in reasonable terms that solution can be said to "educate" readers on the solution. It is not strictly limited to teachers in a traditional classroom setting.

Comment: @TylerH Sure, the risk may be very low and if you even think it's non-existing, feel free to post your own answer. The part with "all such content must have appropriate attribution" however is clear. Thanks for this.

Comment: FWIW, the "fair use" exception also explicitly enumerates other methods that could easily be argued to apply: commentary, research, and scholarship, if you have bones to pick with "teaching" in particular. RE: posting my own answer, I don't think it is worthwhile because the answer I would post exists already in the form of Cody's answer. The issue raised by these comment is specific only to the argument you raise about quoting a GitHub issue comment being illegal without express permission from the author.

Comment: @TylerH I think you gave additional arguments, but they could also just be an edit to Cody's answer or remain here. To summarize: it all hinges on "fair use". And I think I actually leave this open in my answer, even explicitly state that one can argue like this and that's what you did then.

Comment: It wouldn't make much logical sense for the paraphrased version to be acceptable if simply quoting it isn't, given that there are so few changes (even if you're changing it *a lot*, the problem is still that you're only making language changes - you're not changing the actual gist of the content). But then I suppose the law can be weird sometimes (and an actual legal challenge is highly unlikely in any case).

Comment: @NotThatGuy "It wouldn't make much logical sense for the paraphrased version to be acceptable if simply quoting it isn't..." One requires your own work, the other one doesn't. And even if the changes are only small (there may not be many ways to express the same thought) it's still something that might make a difference legally. Please note that the paraphrased version is slightly shorter, which made it a tiny bit better.

Answer (score 25):

As long as you follow the [attribution/referencing requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), then it is fine.

Those requirements are:

1. **Crediting** the original author/source **by name** (if the name can be found),
2. **Linking** directly to the original source,
3. Proper use of **blockquote formatting** to demarcate *all* copied content.

It looks to me like you have followed them, so you are good as far as Stack Overflow's rules are concerned.

Obviously, as the above-linked Help Center article notes, we would *prefer* that your contributions be *original*. But, sometimes, there's just nothing more that needs to be said. This is not a site for sharing original research, after all. Most of what is discussed here is a retread of others' efforts, including but not limited to what can be found in the documentation. It is *essential* that you quote—or at least *summarize*—the information in order to stave off the inevitable effects of link rot (i.e., avoid a "link-only" answer).

Note that moderators do not enforce copyright claims or third-party licenses. They intervene *only* in cases of outright plagiarism, primarily on *ethical* grounds rather than *legal* ones (in which cases, they demand that the author of the post either provide appropriate attribution or delete the post). It is not expected that users attempt to enforce copyrights, either. Copyright law in the United States is extremely complex, and no contributor to Stack Overflow is expected to know the ins and outs of it. All they are expected to do is to act with good faith. For those who are still concerned with laws, note the following points:

- Anything that could reasonably be posted to Stack Overflow with the aim of teaching others falls under the scope of "fair usage", as long as you comply with the attribution/referencing requirements stated above. This most definitely includes a snippet of the nature discussed here.
- Stack Overflow operates within a "safe harbor" provision of United States copyright law, in which the burden for copyright violations (*e.g.*, via DMCA) is placed upon the *claimant*. There is no expectation that the site or its maintainers deal with possible copyright infringement on a proactive basis. The law requires only that legal agents of the site (*i.e.*, staff—again, not moderators or community members) comply with properly documented and warranted requests for removal.

Therefore, individual contributors do not need to be concerned with anything other than contributing content in good faith, following reasonable presumptions of fair use and complying with all attribution requirements. This is all that moderators concern themselves with. If the holder of the copyright decides to take issue with an individual contribution, their avenue for seeking redress is a DMCA takedown notice.

Lots of people try to make this more complicated than it is, because it seems like copyrights, licenses, and other legal stuff should be complicated. They are, of course, but not in the context of enforcement or expectations applied to individual contributors on this site.

Comment: The attribution guidelines typically apply to reproducing content from SO elsewhere, not for including content from elsewhere on SO, which is a different case and different rules may apply, unless the license of the content on GitHub is similar to the license here. But you don't link to any possible attribution requirements for GitHub.

Comment: @Trilarion We don't enforce third-party licenses on Stack Overflow. Quoting content from elsewhere doesn't re-license it, anyway.

Comment: "Quoting content from elsewhere doesn't re-license it, anyway" – That is not how I would interpret "You agree that any and all content, […] that you provide to the public Network ([…]), is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to [CC BY-SA 4.0], and you grant Stack Overflow the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to [lots of stuff]". There is no distinction being made as to who is the original IP rights holder of the content being licensed to SO, Inc. "Any and all content", regardless of its provenance, is …

Comment: … licensed to SO, Inc. when you post it to the network.

Comment: If you do not *own* the content, @Jörg, then you cannot license it to Stack Overflow.

Comment: "We don't enforce third-party licenses on Stack Overflow." That's not true. There is the DMCA mechanism. For example: https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4050/my-post-was-removed-due-to-dmca-takedown-notice-what-can-i-do

Comment: When I say "we", @Trilarion, I mean the community and community moderators. Moderators explicitly *do not* enforce DMCA takedowns. Those are limited to staff.

Comment: @CodyGray Exactly, if you do not own the content then you cannot license it. Do you own the content from Github? No, so don't post it. Unless Github (i.e. the author of the Github comment) does licence it to you in way that is compatible with CC-BY-SA 4.0. There might be some "fair use doctrine" exceptions for small excerpts of course.

Comment: @CodyGray "We don't enforce third-party licenses on Stack Overflow." - uh, but you DO respond to DMCA requests et cetera. Interesting that a mod would post instructions that basically say "you don't have to care about copyright of 3rd party sources lol"... or is the assumption that anything which fits into the SO answer box falls under fair use?

Comment: @l4mpi Mods do not respond to DMCA requests. We would decline those. Yes, this is an issue of fair usage and also of providing attribution to the original source. There seems to be a lot of confusion with regards to people thinking that quoting something counts as somehow relicensing it. It does not. The original license remains intact.

Comment: @CodyGray mods might not respond to DMCA requests but Stack Overflow certainly does (or at least did in the past), so whoever handles those DMCA requests at SO might take issue with your answer. Also, not sure what quoting/relicensing has to do with this - if you copy stuff from whereever else verbatim, then either a) the source must have a compatible license which allows reposting it to SO, or b) the excerpt must be small enough (or adapted enough) to fall under fair use, or c) it's copyright infringement.

Comment: I thought the original answer by the OP was a bit too much quoted material, too little own content, and I would think it failed the _"Do not copy the complete text of external sources"_ from that help page.

Comment: No, @l4mpi, this is the consistent recommendation from staff for the past decade, even from the ones who handle DMCA requests. This answer is not breaking new ground, despite the tempest that seems to be occurring in the comments here. Moderators do not enforce DMCA requests, and they should not concern themselves with them at all. Neither moderators nor site users should concern themselves with third-party licenses/copyrights. Anything you would reasonably post to Stack Overflow with the aim of teaching others falls under fair usage, including, of course, this quotation in question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel While I understand your concerns, do you think it would somehow be better for the answerer to feebly paraphrase the small amount of content that is actually there? I think that would be much worse. I would rather get explicit credit for my efforts, and have them reproduced in my own words with appropriate attribution, than to have someone else put words in my mouth. The Help Center is attempting to *encourage* users to post original content, as I've done, but if you're just going to be paraphrasing the prior efforts of others, quoting and giving explicit credit is preferable.

Comment: "Neither moderators nor site users should concern themselves with third-party licenses/copyrights." It's probably been clear already from me having written a different answer, but I don't agree with the notion. All site users including moderators should strive to not compromise the content stored on Stack Overflow in any way which includes paying attention to the legality of the material they use. But this is just my opinion and I think we simply disagree here.

Comment: "...if you're just going to be paraphrasing the prior efforts of others.." Usually the reason for encouraging paraphrasing is that this allows to specifically adapt other knowledge to the specific cases here. Seldom it's an exact match and you need to summarize other resources anyway. Not really here though.